# Vue.js add class with dynamic values

Tags: html, validation, vue.js

I have a set of errors which are passed to the page via json which are as follows;

```
"errors": [
    {
      "additional.1": [
        "[errored] field is required."
      ]
    },
    ....
]
```

In vue.js html I'm trying to add a class to the field which has errored, by using the :class attribute. Basically I need to see if errors[0][additional.1] is not undefined. The only trouble I'm having is with [additional.[builder.key]]. There doesn't seem to be a way of evaluation this so it equates to additional.1 or whatever builder.key should be.

```
 <div :class="{'has-error' : typeof errors[$index] != 'undefined' && typeof errors[$index][additional.[builder.key]] != 'undefined' }" >
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: What is `builder.key` where is defined?

Comment: In the element above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wil extract the code into a method to make it more readable and clean up the template:

```
<div :class="{'has-error': hasErrorAtIndex($index)}">
```

JS:

```
methods: {
  hasErrorAtIndex: function (index) {
    return typeof this.errors[index] != 'undefined' && this.errors[index].hasOwnProperty('additional.' + this.builder.key)
  }
}
```

...assuming I guessed the context of `builder.key` correctly

Comment: Great this is really clean and works well. Thank you very much.